# How to use ILGenerator got the exe file?

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction

I'm learning how to use ILGenerator,I find some sample(can't find lots):
https://devtut.github.io/csharp/ilgenerator.html#creates-a-dynamicassembly-that-contains-a-unixtimestamp-helper-method

the first example works fine,I can got a dll file.but if the code I want to use  ILGenerator to generate have a main function:

```
public static void main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(UnixTimestamp(EpochTime));
        }
```

can I use ILGenerator to got a exe file,not a dll file?Thanks!

Comment: Just pass a file name with `.exe` as the extension to `Save`. See the example in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.assemblybuilder.save?view=netframework-4.8.1

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/62591